# Xamarin Realm Invalidate Method

Tags: xamarin, realm

> A Realm holds a read lock on the version of the data accessed by it, so that changes made to the Realm on different threads do not modify or delete the data seen by this Realm. Calling this method releases the read lock, allowing the space used on disk to be reused by later write transactions rather than growing the file

Is there a matching function in `Xamarin.Realm` like in Objc/Swift's RLMRealm [invalidate](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(im)invalidate).

If not, is this a backlog item or is it not required(?) with the C# wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I think calling `Realm.Refresh()` would be a workaround - it will cause the Realm instance to relinquish the read lock it has at the moment and move it to the latest version which would free up the old version for compaction.

Ordinarily moving the read lock to the latest version would happen automatically if the thread you run on has a running `CFRunLoop` or `ALooper`, but on a dedicated worker thread you'd be responsible for calling `Refresh()` on your own to advance the read lock.

Please open an issue on https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet for `Invalidate()` if `Refresh()` doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use `Realm.Close()`. See:
https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/class_realms_1_1_realm.html#a7f7a3199c392465d0767c6506c1af5b4

> Closes the Realm if not already closed. Safe to call repeatedly. Note that this will close the file. Other references to the same database on the same thread will be invalidated.

Comment: Thanks, I really do not want to dispose the Realm instance (close is obsolete) as the instance is running on an internal thread : https://github.com/sushihangover/RealmThread